# Need a function that measure the proximity of a given value to a target value

Tags: functions, elementary-functions

Like the title says, I'm looking for a function that take a given value, and returns a value between 0 and 1 which measures how much the given value is near to a target value. Ideally, the returned value should increase faster when the target value is almost reached. For example, if the target is 10:

- Input = 5; output = 0.5
- Input = 8; output = 0.85 (more than 0.8 because we are near to the target)
- Input = 10; output = 1 (of course)
- Input = 15; output = 0.5 (because we have exceed the target)

Any help?

---

EDIT 1

- The function only takes non negative numbers.
- The input number can be at most twice the target number

---

EDIT 2

This is what have I done so far:

```
if (amount <= target)
    return amount / target;
else if (amount >= 2 * target)
    return 0;
else
    return 1 - ( amount % target ) / target;
```

It's very rudimental, and it doesn't implement the concept of "speed".

---

EDIT 3

The goal is to use the function for an automatic optimizer. I have a set of features, and the idea behind is to assign a score to the value assigned to each feature. The more the assigned value is near to the target value, the merrier. I'm using a maximizer to maximize the sum of the scores.

Comment: There are infinitely many functions that satisfy your requirement.  If the function is differentiable at the target, though, the derivative will be $0$, so your requirement that the speed is increasing won't be satisfied.  Therefore, it sounds to me like you should be looking for a function with a cusp at the target, and a vertical tangent there.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I have very little mathematical competence, I just need to use this function in an app I'm creating

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CuspMap.html

Comment: I still don't get how to implement the target value in the cusp function

Comment: That's an example of a function with a cusp.  As I've already said, there are infinitely many functions that satisfy the requirements you've listed.  You need to specify a whole lot more.  To begin with, does the function only take values $\geq0$?  For what values should the function be defined?  Can they be negative?  How big can they be?  All these clarifications should be made by **editing the question body**, not by responding with another comment.

Comment: I've answered your questions in the body, let me know if you need to know more, thank you

Comment: You could try something like $\;1-\left|\dfrac at-1\right|^c\;$ with $c$ near $1.1$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason that there are not answers is because there are many options and it really does depend on how you are going to use this. For example, if it's for an automatic optimizer, usually you want something that goes to zero and you use a minimizer.

You don't care that it's non-differentiable at the cusp?

Based on the description so far, how about

$$f(x, x_0, a) = \exp(-a|x-x_0|)$$

First plot is for $x_0=10$ and $a=0.4$

Or you can try

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(f(x, x_0, 0.2) + f(x, x_0, 2)\right)$$

to get some accelerated "hot zone".

[image: sharp and sharper] click for full size

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, x0, a):
    return np.exp(-a * np.abs(x-x0))

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 1001)

if True:
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, f(x, 10, 0.4))
    plt.plot(x, 0.5*(f(x, 10, 0.2) + f(x, 10, 2)))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: The goal is to use the function for an automatic optimizer. I have a set of features, and the idea behind is to assign a score to the value assigned to each feature. The more the assigned value is near to the target value, the merrier. I'm using a maximizer to maximize the sum of the scores.

Comment: @Andrea the more information in the question to begin with, the merrier also! Do you like the pointy cusp on top? Are you sure you don't want a rounded top?  If you add a bunch of cusps the sum looks like a forest of cusps and the maximizer just might get stuck sitting on one cusp and ignore the others totally. You are looking for a [merit function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeritFunction.html), see also [What is the merit function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1176526)

Comment: I've implemented the function you provided, and as you guessed the pointy cusp is problematic. A rounded top may function better. However, I've read the description of merit function, and it looks like it is exactly what I'm trying to achieve! Do you have any example I could test?

Comment: @Andrea its a general term for what you want, that's all. We all still have to write our own. Least squares minimization works so well in so many cases, it's hard for me to think about using maximization. You square the differences add them, e.g. $(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 +$... and then minimize that. You can weight then differently by putting a different constant in front of each one if one is more sensitive than another. Are you sure that you absolutely must use a maximizer? Least squares is the gold standard; it's simple, universal and robust.

Comment: I've started with a maximizer because I had in my mind the idea of score, but I can switch to a minimizer in no time!

Comment: @Andrea okay great! I'll add more about least squares and propose a few ways to convert it to a positive score in a few hours.